# Calculate the output of an operation between two dataframes conditionally

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have these two dataframes:

```
set.seed(123)
df1<-data.frame(rep=rep(1:4,each=360),parc=rep(1:40,each=36),trat=rep(sample(1:10),each=36),tree=rep(1:36,40),med=1,dap_prev=rnorm(1440, mean = 12))
df2<-data.frame(med=rep(1:18,each=10),trat=rep(sample(1:10)),b0=rnorm(180),b1=rnorm(180))
```

In `df2` I need to retrieve the values of `df2$b0` and `df2$b1` when they match the criteria `df1$med == df2$med` and `df1$trat == df2$trat`. Then create a new column in `df1` whose product is `df2$b0 + df2$b1 * df1$dap_prev`.

I tried with this command below, but of course it did not work:

```
df1$ddap_cm <- df2$b0[df2$med == df1$med & df2$trat == df.1$trat] + df2$b1[df1$med == df2$med & df1$trat == df2$trat] * df1$dap_prev
```

Comment: Your code works, use `df1$trat` instead of `df.1$trat`. But I don't know if it gives you the intended result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I got you right, so I propose this two-step answer

```
set.seed(123)
df1<-data.frame(rep=rep(1:4,each=360),parc=rep(1:40,each=36),trat=rep(sample(1:10),each=36),tree=rep(1:36,40),med=1,dap_prev=rnorm(1440, mean = 12))
df2<-data.frame(med=rep(1:18,each=10),trat=rep(sample(1:10)),b0=rnorm(180),b1=rnorm(180))

### Answer
library(dplyr)
df1_v2 <- left_join(df1, df2, by = c("med", "trat")) # matching with "med" and "trat"
df1_v2$ddap_cm <- df1_v2$b0 + (df1_v2$b1*df1_v2$dap_prev) # new variable
str(df1_v2)
```